# Can anyone please tell me what will be the final charge distribution?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, energy, charge, capacitance

What happens after we close the switch,

(a) $c_1=$ capacitance of the upper parallel plate capacitor having $Q_1$ charge

(b) $c_2 =$ capcitance of the lowerparallel plate capacitor having $Q_2$ charge $(Q1>Q2)$

I think that the charge flows from the plates having higher potential to lower potential till $q_1/C_1=q_2/C_2$ where $q_1$ and $q_2$ are the final charges on $c_1$ and $c2$ respectively.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final steady state is such that the total charge $Q_1+Q_2$ is redistributed between the two capacitors so that the potential difference across both of the capacitors is the same.